# InnerHtml of elementRef of component created dynamically by componentFacory not containing binded values

Tags: angular, data-binding, innerhtml, viewchild, elementref

I have a simple component named component1:
This is its HTML with the bindings and with the template reference:

```
<div class="AAA" [ngClass]="someClass" #templateRef > 
<div class="main-container"> <span> {{someNumber}}</span></div>
</div>
```

This is the component:

```
export class Component1Component implements OnInit { 

@ViewChild('templateRef ', { static: true })      
templateRef : ElementRef;
someNumber : number
someClass : string
get TemplateRef ()
{
   return this.templateRef ;
}
```

Now- In another component, I'm using `ComponentFactoryService` to create this component dynamically, and then set the 2 variables. I would like finally to get the HTML of the component after it is binded:

```
let componentFactory : ComponentFactory<any> = 
this.componentFactoryService.getComponentFacroty(this.componentName); //componentName is Component1Component 
this.componentRef = this.componentContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
/*here I set the variables that should be binded*/
this.componentRef.instance.someNumber = 10;
this.componentRef.instance.someClass = "class1;
```

Now I'm getting the innerHTML **without** the bindind although I can see these binding values in 
 the `component1Component` `oninit` function.

```
var htmlAfterBindind = this.componentRef.instance.templateRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
```

Comment: I can only means that view is not rendered yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure change detection has run on `Component1Component` before trying to access the rendered DOM.

To do that, you can call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` before accessing the innerHTML:

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

```js
this.componentRef = this.componentContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);

/*here I set the variables that should be binded*/
this.componentRef.instance.someNumber = 10;
this.componentRef.instance.someClass = "class1;

/* Call detectChanges to render the DOM */
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

/* Now the DOM is ready */
let htmlAfterBindind = this.componentRef.instance.templateRef.nativeElement.innerHTML;
```